# How to pipe in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to use the pipe function in dplyr and left_join to clean some meta data up.  Setting up variables....

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

mdat <- read.xlsx("https://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article/file?type=supplementary&id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.ppat.1005511.s011",
                  startRow = 3, fillMergedCells = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(sample=Accession.Number)

dge$samples$sample=
 [1] "SRR1346026" "SRR1346027" "SRR1346028" "SRR1346029" "SRR1346030" "SRR1346031" "SRR1346032" "SRR1346033" "SRR1346034"
[10] "SRR1346035" "SRR1346036" "SRR1346037" "SRR1346038" "SRR1346039" "SRR1346040" "SRR1346041" "SRR1346042" "SRR1346043"
[19] "SRR1346044" "SRR1346045" "SRR1346046" "SRR1346047" "SRR1346049" "SRR1346048" "SRR1346050" "SRR1346051" "SRR1346052"
```

I am trying to pipe in the dge$samples$sample, which is a character class.  It needs to become a data frame of one column named sample so I can merge mdat with it by left join in order to remove all the metadata I don't have a sample for.  If you run dim(mdat) you will find it is 35 by 15, I want to reduce it to the 19 samples I actually have data for, these are given in the dge$samples$sample list.  I am trying to use the following code to first convert dge$samples$sample into a data frame with one column titled sample for joining the two and essentially removing all metadata that is not of interest to me.  The code below has been my progress so far but I think I am failing to understand how pipe works.

```
test = data.frame(dge$samples$sample) %>%
  colnames(.) = c("sample") %>%
  left_join(
  .,
  mdat,
  by = sample,
  copy = FALSE,
  suffix = c(".x", ".y"),
  keep = FALSE,
  na_matches = c("na", "never")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just check if theyre in there and filter them:

```r
mdat %>% filter( sample %in% dge$samples$sample )
```

It's easier to understand and controll than a join and performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code can be reduced to

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data.frame(sample = dge$samples$sample) %>%
          left_join(mdat, by = 'sample')
```

Or an inner join should work as well, using base R :

```
test <- merge(data.frame(sample = dge$samples$sample), mdat, by = 'sample')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
sbt(mdat, sample %in% dge$samples$sample)
```